# Export blog posts with MathJax to LaTeX document?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, export, latex, plugin-mathjax

I use [MathJax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mathjax-latex/) to blog my mathematical thoughts. Is it possible to convert my WordPress posts (with plenty of math) into a LaTeX document? The plugin should prompt me to select posts for the paper, and should do the rest automatically.

Comment: you want to convert mathjax to latex?

Comment: Mathjax is a rendering engine that renders Latex / MathML. So, the chances are that your equations are already in Latex.

Comment: yeah... but I want Latex document (paper) not only formula

Comment: @user3047: Did you know you can de-associate and then re-associate all your Stack Exchange accounts to [get a +100 rep boost on all sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5909/how-do-reputation-bonuses-for-associations-between-accounts-work) because you have more than 200 rep on at least one of them?

Comment: Didn't know that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WPTeX](http://xhtml-css.com/wptex/) allows you to convert your WordPress blog to a LaTeX document. If it does not already contain support for inline LaTeX, it should be really easy to add it.

Answer (score 1):

[WP QuickLaTeX](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/quicklatex/) allows native LaTeX syntax to be used directly in Wordpress posts making conversion to offline paper as easy as "copy-paste".

It supports standard inline and displayed math environments (including AMS-LaTeX), displayed equation numbering/referencing by LaTeX rules (\label, \ref). No alien tags ([latex], or else) are required - only pure LaTeX code.

Besides you can use your own LaTeX preamble for equations on your site (define commands and use any LaTeX extension packages from TeXLive 2011 distribution).

This makes exchange with offline papers (and vice versa) a straightforward process.

P.S. We also support rendering of TikZ graphics directly in the post.